# Looking for a good introduction to modelling ARCH-type models

Tags: volatility, reference-request, econometrics, garch

I am starting to think about my dissertation topic for my undergraduate degree.

I am interested in comparing volatility of stock indices during COVID-19 to the years leading up to the pandemic. I have conducted some research and, when modelling volatility, most others seem to use some form of the ARCH model.

If anyone could give me some introductory, or comprehensive, reading on how to create these models (or volatility models in general) it would be greatly appreciated.

As a side note, I have not taken any econometrics models as of yet, however I feel like I have quite a sound mathematical ability.

Thank you in advance, any guidance will be humbly received.

Levi

Comment: Standard textbooks for time series are [Hamilton](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Time-Analysis-James-Douglas-Hamilton/dp/0691042896/ref=pd_lpo_14_t_0/257-2927656-5281701?_encoding=UTF8&pd_rd_i=0691042896&pd_rd_r=8db995a9-88a7-42f1-979a-4f3db3f035af&pd_rd_w=7GM7S&pd_rd_wg=o95WH&pf_rd_p=7b8e3b03-1439-4489-abd4-4a138cf4eca6&pf_rd_r=20WV801K8Y3R3AGKDJ8B&psc=1&refRID=20WV801K8Y3R3AGKDJ8B) and [Tsay](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Analysis-Financial-Wiley-Probability-Statistics/dp/0470414359). [Engle's original paper](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1912773?seq=1#metadata_info_tab_contents) is well-written.

Comment: See some [similar (though not identical) requiests on Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5breferences%5d%20%5btime-series%5d%20textbook), e.g. ["Books or tutorials for GARCH(1,1)"](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/239514) though the suggestion in the answer there is probably too advanced.

Comment: Okay, thank you both for your suggestions!

Comment: I like “Applied Optimal Estimation” by Arthur Gelb - maybe a bit out of your reach, but a good resource and “An Introduction to Sequential Monte Carl” by Chopin and Papaspiliopoulos if you want more modern applications.

Answer (score 0):

A decent, non-technical overview is "A Good Introduction to GARCH and EWMA (Exponentialy Weighted Moving Average)" by David Harper. You should be able to find this online.

Also see NYU Stern's Vol Lab - the whole Vol Lab site is worth browsing and should be helpful to you. The overview of GARCH models is at: https://vlab.stern.nyu.edu/docs/volatility.

HTH.

Comment: Great, thank you. I'll start with those then!